# Active Directory merger

Tags: active-directory, admt

I have 2 domains that I need to merge. For examples sake lets name them like so:
Domain 1: Cat
Domain 2: Dogs.com

Domain 1 is a single homed domain, which makes everything more fun. Both domains have AD installed. Cat is legacy, and Dogs.com will be the new domain.

Cat has all the users, computers, servers, and files. Dogs.com is has a copy of all the users in Cat, and is Dirsynced to Office 365. Dogs.com users need to maintain access to their email.

I  believe the correct tool to do the following is ADMT, but please, correct me if I'm wrong:
I'd like to move over all the resources from Cat into Dogs.com. The ADMT guide directs that users go first, then resources. So all the users and computers from Cat would get migrated to Dogs.com.

After we verify users from Dogs.com can still access File01.cat, File01.cat then would become File01.Dogs.com. All the previously migrated users that are now in Dogs.com would still be able to access the newly migrated File01.Dogs.com.

Is what I've outlined above just about correct for the normal process of ADMT, and what I aim to achieve?

As an added bonus: 40% of the users are mobile, and only connect to the VPN when needed. How will migrating then with ADMT work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dogs.com already has a copy of all the users, and that's used to sync to O365, why are you migrating users at all? If the names collide, you can't migrate them anyway, so I'm unsure why you're doing this in the way you've described.

You (probably) can't move the users, and SIDHistory can't be used to link the accounts because they won't be migrated. Maybe you could manually insert the CAT SID records into the DOGS user accounts and pretend they were migrated. Then, you can move the resources, which I assume is fileservers and maybe workstations.

Using ADMT to migrate workstations that are only VPN connected will be an interesting problem, and also maybe impossible.